# Does あまり “increase” or “lessen” the negative verb?

Tags: word-usage

For example,「ゼロではないけど、あまり多くない。」

多くない = It is not much
あまり多くない = It is not very much

Is 多くない by itself “smaller” than あまり多くない？ In other words, does あまり lessen the strength of the negative verb 多くない? Or, on the contrary, does あまり reinforce the negative verb and make あまり多くない smaller than 多くない by itself？

Comment: 多くない is an adjective, though. The question may be easier to answer if it were about verbs,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

あまり is "(not) very", and the literal meaning of あまり多くない is "not very large in number/volume". Likewise, あまり嬉しくない is "not very happy" rather than "very unhappy".

Although あまり is primarily used to "soften" the sentence, it does not necessarily correspond to the objective degree of largeness, happiness, etc. The main difference between 嬉しくない and あまり嬉しくない is that the former sounds direct whereas the latter sounds mild and euphemistic; the objective difference in the degree of happiness is often unimportant. When you hear someone say あまり嬉しくなかった, you should not take it like "Oh, so you were happy at least a little, if not *very* happy."

To make a clear contrast between "large" and "very large", you can use そこまで(は), それほど(は) or そんなに(は).

- 多いけど、そこまで多くはない。
  There are many, but not *that* many.
- そこまでは嬉しくなかった。
  I was not *that* happy (although I was happy at least a little).

On the other hand, 多いけどあまり多くない simply sounds confusing.

Comment: Similar difference to ‘not _that_ X’ and ‘not very X’ – it’s also quite nonsensical to say, “There are many, but not very many” in English.